# Accessing data from an Array of Structs through a double pointer function variable

Tags: c

I'm working on a function that works as part of a larger program. My C pointer skills are a bit rusty and so I need some help here.

I keep getting segmentation fault errors, and I feel like there is a very trivial solution to my question, and any explanation would help!

Essentially, I have an empty array of structs that I need to pass through to a function as a double pointer. That function will open and read a file saving the contents of the file in the array of structs.

I need to pass it as a double pointer.

This is what I have so far:

```
struct node{
    int first_value;
    int second_value;
};

unsigned char readFunction(char *fileName, int *limit, struct node **arrayToFill){ //Many more variables passed, but I removed it for the sake of simplicity
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("error: could not read the input file!\n");
    }
    int i=0;
    int temp1, temp2;
    for(i=0; i<(*limit); i++){
        fscanf(input, "(%d, %d)", &temp1, &temp2);
        (*(arrayToFill+i))->first_value = temp1;
        (*(arrayToFill+i))->second_value= temp2;
    }
    //More code
    return 0; //Actually returns another array but that's irrelevant.
} 

int main(){
    //NOTE: I just created these variables for the sake of showing it on StackOverflow, I still get a Segmentation Fault error when I run the program.
    char name[9] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '.', 't','x','t', '\0'};
    struct node arrayToPass[10];
    struct node *pointer = &arrayToPass;
    struct node **data = &pointer;
    unsigned char returnedVal;
    int limit = 10;

    returnedVal = readFunction(&name, &limit, data);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, `pointer` is not `struct node **arrayToFill` type but `struct node *arrayToFill` type. Please enable compiler warnings and listen to them.

Comment: heed the `[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]` warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/B-CKfG

Comment: Oops, my bad. As I wrote in the comment in the code, I just created those variables for the sake of not having to put my entire program on SO. I've edited my question. My original problem still stands unfortunately.

Comment: @yano do you mind providing a solution that can help me? I've tried many different combinations and I keep getting that error.

Comment: Please still enable compiler warnings. `&arrayToPass` has the type `struct node (*)[10]` not `struct node *`. It's a pointer to an array of 10 nodes, not a pointer to a node. So you want just `(*arrayToFill)[i].first_value`? What would be the point of passing a pointer? So the `readFunction(..., pointer);` should be changed to `readFunction(..., data)`?

Comment: Re “I need to pass it as a double pointer”: Why? “… as I pass it through multiple functions”: That does not make sense. A `struct node *` can be received by a function as a parameter and passed on to another function in the same way. A need to pass something through multiple functions does not create a need for a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems. The first is you are using the `arrayToPass[10]` pointer incorrectly, all you need is:

```
int main (void) {

    struct node arrayToPass[10];
    int limit = 10;

    printf ("return: %hhu\ncontent:\n", readFunction(NULL, &limit, &arrayToPass));
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        printf ("%5d   %5d\n", 
                arrayToPass[i].first_value, arrayToPass[i].second_value);

}
```

Do not attempt to cast around your `struct node (*arrayToPass)[10]` pointer when you pass the address by assigning to different pointers. You begin with type `struct node [10]` (*array of struct node [10]*) when you take the address you have `struct node (*)[10]` (*pointer to array of struct node [10]*). It is separate and district from `struct node **` (*pointer to pointer to struct node*).

Your function then takes the type `struct node (*arrayToFill)[10]`, e.g.

```
unsigned char readFunction (char *fileName, int *limit, struct node (*arrayToFill)[10])
{ //Many more variables passed, but I removed it for the sake of simplicity
    FILE *input;
    input = fileName ? fopen (fileName, "r") : stdin;
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("error: could not read the input file!\n");
    }
    int i=0;
    int temp1, temp2;
    while (i < *limit && fscanf(input, " (%d, %d)", &temp1, &temp2) == 2) {
        (*arrayToFill)[i].first_value = temp1;
        (*arrayToFill)[i].second_value = temp2;
        i++;
    }
    *limit = i;

    return 0; //Actually returns another array but that's irrelevant.
}
```

(**note:** the use of the *ternary operator* allowing `NULL` to be passed as `fileName` to read from `stdin` -- that was just for my convenience)

(**also note:** that since you declare `struct node arrayToPass[10];` with automatic storage duration in `main()`, you don't need to pass the address of the pointer, you only need to pass the address of the pointer if the address can changes in your function -- such as if you call `realloc` on the pointer. The other answer addresses that point.)

The difference between needing to pass `struct node **` or `struct node (*)[10]` or simply `struct node *` boils down to how memory is allocated for the original collection. If as you have done, declaring `struct node arrayToPass[10];` in `main()` with *automatic storage duration*, storage for the array is fixed. On access, the array is converted to a pointer (`struct node *`) and you can simply pass the array itself as the parameter. (but you are limited to no more than the number of elements originally declared)

If however, you have an *allocated storage type* for `arrayToPass` in `main` (e.g. `struct node *arrayToPass = malloc (10 * sizeof *arrayToPass);`, then if you need to change the amount of storage, e.g. the number of `stuct node` that your allocated block of memory can hold in `readFunction()`, then you must pass the address of the pointer, so if reallocation takes place, and the beginning address for your block of memory changes, that change will be seen back in the caller (`main()` here). In that case when you pass the address of `struct node *`, then your type becomes `struct node **`. (because you have taken the address of a *pointer* instead of the address of an *array*)

Since your *arrayToPass* can't be reallocated, and the storage is fixed before it is passed to `readFunction()`, you don't need to pass the address and you can eliminate one level of pointer indirection and just pass the array as type `struct node *`. That simplifies access in your function to simply `arrayToFill[i].first_value = temp1;`, the `[..]` acting as a dereference of the pointer, just as `->` does.

You also may want to change the return type from `unsigned char` to `size_t` and return the number of elements filled in your struct (a meaningful return) -- or you can update the `limit` pointer as I did -- your choice.

The complete example is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int first_value;
    int second_value;
};

unsigned char readFunction (char *fileName, int *limit, struct node (*arrayToFill)[10])
{ //Many more variables passed, but I removed it for the sake of simplicity
    FILE *input;
    input = fileName ? fopen (fileName, "r") : stdin;
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("error: could not read the input file!\n");
    }
    int i=0;
    int temp1, temp2;
    while (i < *limit && fscanf(input, " (%d, %d)", &temp1, &temp2) == 2) {
        (*arrayToFill)[i].first_value = temp1;
        (*arrayToFill)[i].second_value = temp2;
        i++;
    }
    *limit = i;

    return 0; //Actually returns another array but that's irrelevant.
} 

int main (void) {

    struct node arrayToPass[10];
    int limit = 10;

    printf ("return: %hhu\ncontent:\n", readFunction(NULL, &limit, &arrayToPass));
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        printf ("%5d   %5d\n", 
                arrayToPass[i].first_value, arrayToPass[i].second_value);

}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/2x8rand.txt
(17987, 1576)
(12911, 4488)
(30688, 5875)
(25617, 16643)
(8999, 26249)
(29270, 31857)
(8954, 2094)
(21390, 27676)
```

Note the change in the `fscanf` *format-string* including an additional `' '` (space) before the opening parenthesis `'('` to consume the `'\n'` (and any leading whitespace). You cannot use any input function correctly unless you ***check the return*** (e.g. `fscanf(input, " (%d, %d)", &temp1, &temp2) == 2`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptrtoarraystruct < dat/2x8rand.txt
return: 0
content:
17987    1576
12911    4488
30688    5875
25617   16643
 8999   26249
29270   31857
 8954    2094
21390   27676
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It is not likely OP wants a parameter type of `struct node (*)[10]`. They asked for `struct node **`, and it is likely `struct node *` would actually suffice for them, with some explanation about why they do not need `struct node **`.

Comment: Good point, all add to the paragraph where I talked about the `struct node *` being shown in the other answer.

Comment: WOW, thank you so much for the very detailed explanation! I really appreciate you taking your time to write that! You've covered all my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want something like the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node{
    int first_value;
    int second_value;
};

unsigned char readFunction(char *fileName, int limit, struct node *arrayToFill){ //Many more variables passed, but I removed it for the sake of simplicity
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("error: could not read the input file!\n");
    }
    int i=0;
    int temp1, temp2;
    for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
        fscanf(input, "(%d, %d)", &temp1, &temp2);
        arrayToFill[i].first_value = temp1;
        arrayToFill[i].second_value = temp2;
    }
    //More code
    return 0; //Actually returns another array but that's irrelevant.
} 

int main(){
    //NOTE: I just created these variables for the sake of showing it on StackOverflow, I still get a Segmentation Fault error when I run the program.
    char name[9] = "test.txt";
    struct node arrayToPass[10];
    unsigned char returnedVal;
    int limit = 10;

    returnedVal = readFunction(name, limit, arrayToPass);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Close, I know I can just remove one pointer, but it needs to be a double pointer, as I pass it through multiple functions. I should've made that clear. Thanks anyways!